# Migrating PostgreSQL into Oracle, Boolean compatibility

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, database-migration, ojdbc

I have one table called `Table A`, It has three fields `aa ab ac`. `ac` is `Boolean` in PostgreSQL, while migrating to `oracle db` I have made it `Number(1)`. But In Back-end code I have written SQL queries like `SELECT * FROM A where ac = true`. **Without changing the SQL query I wanted to get data from oracle db**. Please let me know it is possible or not. If possible then which approach should I follow.

Comment: I doubt that it is possible without changing the query. You will get a syntax error, 'invalid identifier'. `true` may be a boolean value in Postgre; in Oracle it has no special meaning, so the parser will view it as an identifier (a column name or alias). Why do you need to run the SQL query without changes? If you migrate from Postgre to Oracle, you should expect that some queries will have to be adapted to Oracle.

Comment: I want run application on both PostgreSQL and Oracle DB. Like `MySQL` it automatically converts Boolean to 1/0. Can we implement like this in oracle DB.

Comment: Not possible. Oracle does not support boolean in SQL expressions. This would only be possible if you don't use boolean in Postgres and use an integer instead.

Comment: Just change the code

Comment: is there any hack for that??

Comment: I had the issue, I did a piece of Java code with column meta data information only for Boolean as plain inserts. It worked for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the SQL (code).  No other way around it.  Boolean is not supported in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score -1):

If service is python, I suggest you keep it as an integer in PostgreSQL and a check constraint to accept values only 0 or 1. And while mapping i.e in ORM, you can do `int(False)` for 0 and `int(True)` for 1 and then save it to database.

Comment: User clearly expresses Java in the tags.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).